# How does authentication work on Azure Functions

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, authentication, azure-functions, webapi

I have a .Net 5 Web API hosted on Azure App Service.

The API has three Background services running as hosted services, which perform long running processes such as bulk emailing and SMSing, as well as other functionality that runs once a day on a timer.

I am thinking about moving out these hosted/background services into separate Azure Functions, which I would then call / trigger from my API via an HTTP request (except for the one that runs on a timer)

My concern is regarding authentication. How does that work with Azure Functions? Currently, my Web API is using Auth0 as the authentication server. So, when the user uses the front-end web app (Angular), he logs in (via Auth0's login form) and then the front-end retrieves an access/bearer token from AUth0, which it then includes in every call to the API (in an Authentication header).

Now, obviously I don't want just anyone to be able to call the Azure Functions - only my Web API should be able to do so. But how does that work? Does the API need to forward the access token it received from the front end to the Azure Function when calling it? Or is there something I need to set up in Azure Portal to tell it that my API must be allowed access to the Azure Function (and block any requests from any other origin)?

I've never used Azure Functions or even WebJobs before, so I'm a bit lost.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an HTTP-triggered Azure Function, by default it is set to have authorization level = Function, which means that any app trying to invoke that function via its URL needs to know the specific access key that is generated for that function upon creation.

In your example, your web API would store that function's invocation URL and access key in its configuration, and invoke your function with that key. Since the key remains entirely server-side on Azure, nothing else can access it, so it's completely secure.

Depending on your requirements, you can then also layer other types of authorization/authentication (e.g. bearer token) on top of the access key mechanism, or use those instead of access keys (by setting the function to allow anonymous access).

For maximum security, I would recommend using both the function access key as a first step to ensure that nobody except your apps can successfully invoke the function, and then passing along and authenticating the bearer token to ensure that the app trying to invoke that function is indeed permitted to do so.

Just be aware that Azure Functions is a slightly different beast to standard ASP.NET Core, particularly in regards to middleware which it [doesn't really support yet](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1284), so you'll likely need to roll your own code for reading the bearer token from the incoming HTTP request's headers, and verifying that it's valid.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#authorization-keys

Comment: Thank you Ian, I will try that. I think, at least for now, the default access key authorization level will work great. Like you said, both the Web API and the Function are hosted on Azure App Service, so it's probably ok to store the access key in a configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, you just need to enable "**Authentication/Authorization**" of your function app.

[image]

Follow the steps in the screenshot above and when you click the forth red box, choose "**Express**" tab and click "**ok**" at the bottom of the page without do anything. It will create an application in your Azure AD which has same name with your function app.
[image]

After that, when you request the function app url in browser, it will ask you to login.

For more details of the steps, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad).

Answer (score 1):

Hury's guidance is best - you want to avoid using API keys on your production functions and use this just for testing. Official guidance is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production

Configure your Functions for AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, and require Authentication on your Function as Hury describes. This will not only require end users to authenticate, but supports System Assigned Managed Identity when your function is called from other App Services. Less keys to vault or configure means less to steal.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by authentication.
If you just want to secure your functions you can use the authorization level = function.
However, if you need authentication with login, and you need to know the user making the request, you have to use bearer token with OpenIDConnect server.
Always use stateless authentication regardless your method.